# jq コマンドで特定の文字列を抽出したい

Tags: json, jq

ここからidに当たる7721291801を `jq` コマンドで取得したいです。

```js
{
    "total_count": 1,
        "entries": [
        {
            "type": "group",
            "id": "7721291801",
            "name": "test-group1",
            "group_type": "managed_group"
        }
        ],
        "limit": 100,
        "offset": 0
}
```

以下のコマンドを実行するとエラーとなります。

**実行したコマンド:**

```
curl -i -X GET "https://api.box.com/2.0/groups" -H "Authorization: Bearer xxxxxxxxxx" | jq -R 'fromjson?' | jq '.[].id'
```

**エラーメッセージ:**

```
jq: error (at <stdin>:13): Cannot index number with string "id"
```

IDの値を抽出する方法を教えていただきたいです。

Comment: `entries` があるので `'.entries[]|.id'` とすれば良いかと思いますが、`.entries[]` を指定しないで `id` の値を取り出したいということなのでしょうか？

Answer (score 0):

`entries`以下を取り出したい場合はコメントにあるように`jq '.entries[]|.id'`となると思います。
不定な階層の子要素からidをすべて取り出したい場合は`jq '..|.id?|select(.!=null)'`で探し出せそうです。

参考: [jqでJSONの深い階層を気にせずにアクセスする](https://www.greptips.com/posts/1309/)

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。
問題なく抽出出来ることを確認致しました。

Answer (score 0):

ファイルを標準入力から渡して動作確認してみました。
 `| jq ..` 以降を見ていただければ。

```sh
cat <<EOF | jq -r '.entries[].id'
{
  "total_count": 1,
  "entries": [
    {
      "type": "group",
      "id": "7721291801",
      "name": "test-group1",
      "group_type": "managed_group"
    }
  ],
  "limit": 100,
  "offset": 0
}
EOF
```

`-r` オプションを付けて置くと良いです。